# How to get HDRI Environmental Maps to light a scene?

Tags: lighting, hdri

[image]I'm using HDRI's in Blender 2.8 (cycles) and I don't understand how these are supposed to work to create realistic environmental light. The BLUE in the "Sky" shots is casting so much BLUE that my entire world looks ridiculous.

**Is there a way to use JUST the sunlight within the HDRI to create more realistic sunlight?**

UPDATE: I think the trick is to ensure that the trees or mid-point of the HDRI is exposed as to cut down on the sheer amount of blue influencing the rendering. This version looks acceptable to me.

Comment: Without seeing the HDRI or your scene all we can do is guess. Many people have used many HDRIs to make many very realistic scenes, so... As to your bolded question - if you want no blue from the HDRI, use a sun lamp instead with nothing for the background.

Comment: http://blog.gregzaal.com/2013/07/24/cif-2-hdr-lighting/ in this nodetree you can add RGB curves to adjust a color Tint.